# Split String by new lines (multiple lines) with different spacing

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the following string which is read in from an external system.

```
var test = @"Order No.: 999\r\n\r\nCustomer ID:\r\n\r\nName:\r\n\r\Comment:\r\nPosition\r\n\r\nCount 20.80"
```

I want to split by new lines

```
var result = test.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

There are two issues the above code does not work only one value is returned, the second issue is that there are differences in the new lines, is there a way I can split this using a different method?

```
\r\n\r\n
\r\n\r\
\r\n
```

Comment: Are you sure it has `\r\n` literally? Usually, `\r\n` is a line break. You don't get line breaks in a verbatim string

Comment: There is a huge difference between `@"\r\n"` and `"\r\n"`. Are you _absolutely_ sure you're working with the former and not the latter? Iff you're sure, you can try `test.Split(new[] {@"\r", @"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`, otherwise remove the `@` before the test string (and fix the `\C` as @Jimi mentions below) and try `test.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: I think that OPs typo... I think the last line is what counts. Or else it would be just weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```cs
private static readonly Regex _getLinesRegex = new Regex("\r\n|\r|\n", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The splitter Method

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Splits a string into lines
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The string to be slitted</param>
        /// <returns>The lines of the string</returns>
        public static string[] GetLines(this string value) => _getLinesRegex.Split(value);
```

Comment: `\r\n` is a line break. Note that OP has `\\r\\n`, which is `\\\\r\\\\n` in Regex

Comment: Also, your solution does not cover the `\r\n\r\C` problem.

Comment: I don’t see any \\r\\n in OPs string. His problem is that his strings is a mix of \n or \r or \r\n... And I don’t see any \C to cover, which is a weird control char. Yes... This solution covers everything you want... Just add those chars in the regex.

Comment: `@"\r\n"` is equivalent to `"\\r\\n"`. Also, `@"\C"` is not a control character. It's `"\\C"`.

Comment: I think it’s OPs typo... Because `\r\n\r\` would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was to answer

> Split by `\r\n` and use [`RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netcore-3.1) as the option.

But then I realized that you use verbatim strings (`@"..."`), so you have `\r\n` literally.

My proposal is to split on the more or less regular literal line breaks and treat all the special stuff specially:

```
var test = @"Order No.: 999\r\n\r\nCustomer ID:\r\n\r\nName:\r\n\r\Comment:\r\nPosition\r\n\r\nCount 20.80";
var result = test.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var s in result)
{
    var fixawkward = s;
    if (fixawkward.StartsWith(@"\r\"))
    {
        fixawkward = fixawkward.Substring(3);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(fixawkward);
}
```

For real world code, I suggest you make that special treatment configurable. Once the external system provides you with correct data, you want to be able to turn your special handling off as soon as possible. Customers don't want to wait 3 months for a new release by you if they upgraded the external system.