# C# Unable to split string by new lines \n

Tags: c#, split, newline

I'm facing a odd problem were C# is unable to split a string for new lines. I tried many combinations like use only Split.('\n') but all lead to return the whole string unsplited on first position of the array so lines[0] is the same as the input string to be splited, that never happen before with other strings i had to parse.

Image bellow:

[image]

String:

> Don't remove the following keywords! These keywords are used in the
> "compatible printer" condition of the print and filament profiles to
> link the particular print and filament profiles to this printer
> profile.\nPRINTER_VENDOR_PRUSA3D\nPRINTER_MODEL_SL1\nPRINTER_VENDOR_EPAX\nPRINTER_MODEL_X1\n\nSTART_CUSTOM_VALUES\nFLIP_XY\nLayerOffTime_0\nBottomLightOffDelay_2\nBottomLiftHeight_5\nLiftHeight_5.5\nBottomLiftSpeed_40.2\nLiftSpeed_60\nRetractSpeed_150\nBottomLightPWM_255\nLightPWM_255\nAntiAliasing_4
> ; Use 0 or 1 for disable AntiAliasing with "printer gamma correction"
> set to 0, otherwise use multiples of 2 and "gamma correction" set to 1
> for enable\nEND_CUSTOM_VALUES

Code:

var lines = previousString.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Output:
An array of lenght = 1 producing lines[0] == previousString

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and don't post [images of code, but the code itself](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889586/split-string-by-new-lines-multiple-lines-with-different-spacing/62889644#62889644

Comment: My hunch is that the text you are splitting doesn't actually have newlines in it: I suspect those are really the two characters: backslash & en. Try splitting on "\\n" to confirm.

Comment: Magnetron i posted a image because it shows the debugger and the proof of the problem. I think 1 line code isn't that dificult to copy from image, all my code is doing is a string.split, nothing more, but i will post the string as text here to be easier to copy it and see. Edited now

Comment: @Jamie F you are right double back slash (\\n) solved the problem, this is odd since i read the text from a file, need to back check it. Thanks you can post it as a anwser so i can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when you see a `\n` on screen it really is a backslash (ASCII 92 and an en(ASCII 110) not a placeholder/escape sequence for new line (ASCII 10) A big hint for that here is that text boxes will usually not display newlines with escape codes but will put in actual new lines.

To split on `\n` use the string `"\\n"` which represents a string of two characters: the two backslashes produce a single character ASCII 92 = '' in the string and then a lowercase n.

Alternately you could use `@"\n"`. The @ sign tells C# not to use escape codes in the quoted string.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
    new[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

edit:

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
    new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNY8a6

See: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net)

Comment: I think you didn't look at my code by your anwser... I tried that and produce same effect, in fact that cover less possibilities than the aproach i'm using { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are using the Printer methods but I hope you don't require them.

```cs
string test = "Hello \nTest \n123"; //Create Test String
string[] seperated = test.Split('\n'); //Splite String by '\n'
        
for(int i = 0; i < seperated.Length; i++){ //Output substrings
    Console.WriteLine(seperated[i]);    
}
```

Output:

```
Hello 
Test
123
```

I hope this solution works for you!

Edit: Added \r\n and \r support
If you also need to split strings by '\r' or '\r\n' then this code is the one to go with.

```cs
string test = "Hello \r\nTest \n123 \rEnd"; //Create Test String
test = test.Replace("\r\n","\n");
test = test.Replace("\r","\n");
string[] seperated = test.Split('\n'); //Splite String by '\n'
    
for(int i = 0; i < seperated.Length; i++){ //Output substrings
    Console.WriteLine(seperated[i]);    
}
```

Output:

```
Hello 
Test 
123 
End
```

Edit2: Hopefully Solution
So you are saying that

```
\nPRINTER_VENDOR_PRUSA3D\nPRINTER_MODEL_SL1\nPRINTER_VENDOR_EPAX\nPRINTER_MODEL_X1\n\nSTART_CUSTOM_VALUES\nFLIP_XY\nLayerOffTime_0\nBottomLightOffDelay_2\nBottomLiftHeight_5\nLiftHeight_5.5\nBottomLiftSpeed_40.2\nLiftSpeed_60\nRetractSpeed_150\nBottomLightPWM_255\nLightPWM_255\nAntiAliasing_4 ; Use 0 or 1 for disable AntiAliasing with "printer gamma correction" set to 0, otherwise use multiples of 2 and "gamma correction" set to 1 for enable\nEND_CUSTOM_VALUES
```

is the string then the problem might be that this string contains some " which will interfere with the .Split method

If you're able to input the string manually you should replace a simple " with a "